# How to add a program to windows 7 program list?

Tags: windows, list, regedit

Can anyone tell me how I can add program to the windows 7 program list? For example Putty or Eclipse. I really love being able to hit the windows key and just start typing the name of the program I want and have windows find it. In the past I've created a shortcut and pinned it to the list but there has to be a way to register putty or eclipse like other software does when it is installed

Comment: StackOverflow is part of a whole range of sites, and unfortunately when you ask a question it isn't smart enough to guide you away to other sites that are more appropriate for your question (yet - maybe some day?). superuser.com would be more appropriate for this question, and it's probably a dupe there - give it a search.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that by adding a shortcut of the program to the path
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs